# Can you dual boot 2 installations of Windows 11?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, encryption

Say there's a case where you want a secure installation of Windows 11 and another normal one for games and less secure stuff.
Could one install Windows 11 on one drive and then encrypt it with BitLocker and then install a second copy of Windows 11 on a separate drive? (without using BitLocker)

I'm asking this because I know Windows 11 requires a TPM module and then it initializes and basically "owns" it on installation, so I'm not sure what would happen if you were to install it twice on the same machine.

Edit: Both copies would have their own license. Additional question: Assuming dual booting would work, since they'd both be sharing the same TPM, wouldn't the non encrypted install have access to the key for the encrypted one?

Comment: In theory Microsoft would prefer both of those copies be licenced separately, but practically that would be difficult to enforce. The TPM has nothing to do with product activation, it is about establishing a chain of trust during booting.

Comment: Maybe I asked this wrong. The copies would be properly licensed, I just want to know if it would work from a technical stand point.

Comment: Then no, there is nothing stopping you from having multiple copies of any operating system and dual/quad or even octo-booting on modern systems.

Comment: @Alex Did you already try this out and does it work seamlessly? I want to do the same.